# Will this database model for review ratings work?

Tags: mysql, database, yii, model, schema

So the image shows my database model for the review/ratings, can it be improved, is anything missing that would prevent me from doing the below/cause problems?

Users will need to be able to rate the review from 1 - 2 (good or bad).

Each review will then say 75% rated good 25% rated bad.

Users will be able to look in there account at reviewS they have rated.
[image]

I know similar questions have been asked before however this is for a final year project and using Yii so want to make sure model is correct before using the Gii feature.

Comment: You may add `ratings_total` int(11) to `rewies` to reducing DB load.

Comment: @SiZE ratings total wouldn't tell me how many people voted good and how many voted bad. Do you suggest adding two fields to reviews table such as rating_total_good and rating_total_bad?

Comment: As you want to show rating in percents. You can store as both, as one. If you store both you just show both. If you store one, you just math the second (100-first)=second. By the way you will (re)calculate param(s) once when user vote instead of every time you show page.